# Running a project won't build other (non-referenced) projects

Tags: c#, build, visual-studio-2015, reference

My solution has a console application (.exe) project that uses several class library projects (.dll). The class library projects have a reference to the console application. The console application loads the class library projects during runtime. (The .exe scans the dll's in the same directory and loads them.)

```
 _________________
|                 | <-- library1.dll
| application.exe | <-- library2.dll
|_________________| <-- library3.dll
```

When I *clean* the solution and then hit *start* or *debug*, Visual Studio only builds that console project (.exe) as it is the Startup project. But it does not build the library projects (.dll), as the console application does not reference the libraries.

If I hit *build* on the library projects directly or on the entire solution, I do get the .dll files. But this is an action I might forget, and so I might end up using the application with no .dll files or with older builds of the .dll files.

I want to make VS2015 build all projects when running or building the console application. I have already tried:

**=>** Making a reference from the console application to the DLL, but failed, as this would give a circular reference.

**=>** Adding build dependencies on the console application project, to also build the library projects. But this is impossible, as Visual Studio claims that would also give a circular reference.

**=>**  Making all projects in the solution to be startup projects. This actually **works** as VS2015 build all projects and creates .exe as .dll files. **But** then I get annoying popups every time I run the application telling me that console application cannot be startup applications.

**=>**  Split up the console application by creating another library projects (connect.dll) that holds the stuff that the other libraries need to reference. And then ALL projects reference the common.dll and the console application can finally reference the console libararies. This also **works**, **but** leaves you with an extra project:

```
 _____________                        _________________   
|             | <------------------- |                 |  
|             | <-- library1.dll <-- |                 |  
| connect.dll | <-- library2.dll <-- | application.exe |
|             | <-- library3.dll <-- |                 |
|_____________|                      |_________________|
```

Is there a **better** way to make VS2015 build also the non-referenced projects, when building the console application project, without adding an entire new project?

Answer (score 0):

Why do the class libraries need a reference to the executable?  Normally the executable references the class libraries (which it sounds like it needs to, judging by the fact you're loading the class library at runtime), and not the other way around.

You need to keep the class libraries from depending on the executable.  If they *must* depend on it, it means you probably have stuff in the executable that belongs in the library.  Either move these things to the library or move *everything* to the same project.

EDIT:  In light of your comment

> But to answer your question: the application contains interfaces of the classes implemented in the libraries and keeps track of all loaded libraries.

The last scenario described in your question seems like the correct set up to me.  Move the interfaces to their own project, each class library (as well as the executable) references the interface project.

Conceptually, this is not an *extra* project -- the fact that the class libraries really only depend on *part* of the existing executable (only the interface part) immediately suggests that the executable had two parts to begin with.  That's where your circular dependency is coming from.

Comment: What you wrote is is not an answer. But to answer your question: the application contains interfaces of the classes implemented in the libraries and keeps track of all loaded libraries. Because the libraries reference the application, the libraries now call each others' code. And by having dll's this way, I can very easily take out or plug in libraries simply by adding / removing a dll file.